# Closing video window using close “X” button in OpenCV with Java

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

Similar to the question at [Closing video window using close "X" button in OpenCV, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307606/closing-video-window-using-close-x-button-in-opencv-python/63256721?noredirect=1#comment119094035_63256721), is there a way to close a Video window with the X button using Java?  Need solution for both Windows and Linux.

The Java version doesn't seem to have a getWindowsProperty() method anywhere.

**Update**
I was not clear that I am trying to use HighGui.imshow(), which unfortunately, does not expose the JFrame to add a listener to it.
See [openCv 4 Java HighGui.imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103815/opencv-4-java-highgui-imshow)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to java.awt.Window, you can always add a window listener to it. See some more info [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-close-awt-window)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I want to use Highgui.ishow(), which unfortunately, doesn't expose the JFrame to add the listener